# what number and/or kind of dynos pick in heroku

Tags: python, heroku, websocket, redis

I'm new in heroku and I wonder what questions should ask to myself to pick a save configuration(number and kind) of dynos in heroku.

If I have a chat like [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-websockets) made in python, gunicorn, redis and websockets to 800 concurrent users. The lifetime of this chat will last few hours(close to 5 hours) and finally when the chat is no longer used I want to recover the last message of each user.

I'm planning take one PX but I'm afraid the system could fail and loose all due to redis save all in RAM so maybe should I take three 3X? or maybe two PX?

And what about redis, [this](https://addons.heroku.com/rediscloud) is the available plans.

Should I use nginx? I think is not necesary, there is almost 90% static pages.

More details:
The info sent in websockets are json with a lenght of 100 tops.

Comment: Your Heroku dynos run the app, but the add-on (e.g. Redis Cloud) are run on separate instances by the provider (i.e. Redis Labs) so you shouldn't worry about that.

Comment: @ItamarHaber but There is something that I don't understand. If i pick 8 instances of 2X dynos the Redis cloud are running on separate instances, so if any dynos falls down then I will loose all data in RAM and finally i could will not get the last message of each user.

Comment: If a dyno fails, everything that it didn't persist to the outside (e.g. Redis or any other datastore) will be lost. From your question it appeared to me as if you were asking what would happen to the data in Redis' RAM once this happens.

Comment: @ItamarHaber ok, then I have to persist data but when a dynos falls down and recovers and it's working again I'm not sure if should I do something special to "sync" data to other redis databases located in other instances? I mean, Is there any shared data between dynos?. Should I worry about I can't access too all data (persisted or RAM) from one dynos?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your app, but if you use Redis to keep the last message, your code should be able to fetch it after a dyno restart

Comment: thanks for help @ItamarHaber I probably try to find the way to save all data in all dynos instances.